# got type inference, want to add class inheritance

Tags: programming-languages, language-design

If I design a new language with type inference, no explicit types and no class inheritance support and then want to add inheritance, what are the *minimum* extra hints to the compiler needed to resolve type ambiguity when adding the feature?

Are class names needed?

EDIT

The type-tainting is traced through assignments throughout the program including between functions.

OK in the starting language, you have class names like `MyTypeName1` from stuff like:

```
myVariable1 = New(MyTypeName1)
myVariable2 = New(MyTypeName2)
```

And types `MyTypeName1` and `MyTypeName2` are inferred for `myVariable1` and `myVariable2` respectively.  But then if we want to enhance the language to support:

```
MyVariable3 = myVariable1
MyVariable3 = myVariable2
```

which can be traced through the code (myVariable3 now can contain two types which presumably are in a hierarchy).

EDIT

The members of MyTypeName1 and MyTypeName2 are inferred from statements like:

```
myVariable1.name="Fred"
myVariable2.name="JX3009"
```

What if the `name` member in `MyTypeName1` and in `MyTypeName2` are not to be in a common base class?  What if we want a different name property in `MyTypeName1` and `MyTypeName2` and none in a base class?  Is there an elegant way to tell the compiler what to do / how to handle?  (The idea with type inference is to reduce typing not increase it...?)

Or do we need to specify the hierarchy explicitly?

Comment: Jim: If it is, I'm glad it's not my homework, cause I'm really struggling to figure out what he's talking about :)

Comment: It's a pleasure to stump you gentlemen. :)

Comment: So I guess what I'm trying to understand is: How is the type inference implemented? What sort of inheritance support? And how can you inherit when you don't have explicit types? Doesn't adding inheritance mean you *will* get explicit types? Or are you suggesting something else?

Comment: I don't think the question as stated has enough context to get a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This field is loaded with undecidability results, but I've forgotten them all.  If you're willing to conflate inheritance with subtyping, then you have no problems.  If you want something more ambitious (and it sounds as if you do), I'd have a look at

- Benjamin Pierce's textbook [Types and Programming Languages](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/), which will cover the basic results for width and depth subtyping and how they do or do not play nicely with type inference.  (I'd look myself but my copy is at work.)
- François Pottier's PhD dissertation.

Another name to check out is Joe Wells, who's been responsible for a lot of undecidability results in type systems and programming languages.

> What are the *minimum* extra hints to the compiler needed to resolve type ambiguity?

If there is a unique answer to this question, I will be very surprised.  I think it far more likely that this is one of those language-design problems where there are a bunch of solutions which are strictly incomparable as far as minimality and annotations go.